# How to append data to a .xls file through Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jxls

I want to append data to a TestData.xls.
TestData.xls already contains data for my scripts. I am reading this data in program, processing it and result-Pass/Fail is decided on this processing.
I want to write back this results to next column in TestData.xls
I have tried like below,

```
for(int i=0;i<rows-1;i++)
        {
        WritableWorkbook wkb = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("E://Testing//testing  Tools//Selenium//TestData//TestData.xls"));
        WritableSheet sh = wkb.createSheet("Agent",0);
        WritableFont f = new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL);
        WritableCellFormat cf = new WritableCellFormat(f);
        sh.addCell(new Label(0,i+1,"Pass",cf));
        wkb.write();
        wkb.close();
        }
```

But it deletes all data previously available in TestData.xls
Then i tried as TestData1.xls but data is not written at correct position and it is partial.

Now I want to append data to next available column of TestData.xls without erasing  previous data.

Please tell me how to append data through Selenium Webdriver

Comment: You solved this problem

Answer (score 1):

For a Starter to this question : This has nothing to do with Selenium WebDriver.

You are trying to insert value to a particular location in xls.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code may be it it useful to you.

`public static void writeReport(String readFileName, String readSheetName, String result, int row,int col) throws BiffException, IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException

```
    {

        File fileWrite = new File(readFileName);

        Workbook in = Workbook.getWorkbook(fileWrite);

        WritableWorkbook writable_workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(fileWrite, in);

        WritableSheet writable_sheet = writable_workbook.getSheet(readSheetName);

        writable_sheet.addCell(new Label(col, row , result));

        writable_workbook.write();

        writable_workbook.close();

    }`
```